# Solve Wave Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, wave-equation

I have to solve the follwing wave equation

$$\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}=4\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}$$

with the boundary conditions

$$u(x,t=0)=0, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t=0)=\sin(x)$$

in the domain $(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R_{+}}$. To solve this I tried to use the D'Alembert solution since the general solution for the simple wave equation is

$$u(x,t)=f(x+2t)+g(x-2t)$$

Then using the initial conditions

\begin{align}
u(x,t=0) &=0 \\
&=f(x)+g(x) \\
u_{t}(x,t=0) &=\sin(x) \\
&=2[f'(x)-g'(x)]
\end{align}

Differentiating the first equation we have the following system

\begin{align}
0 &= f'+g' \\
\frac{\sin(x)}{2} &= f'-g'
\end{align}

and solving for $f'$ and $g'$, we find

$$f' = \frac{\sin(x)}{4}, \quad g' = -\frac{\sin(x)}{4}$$

Then we have that

\begin{align}
f(x+2t) &= \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{x+2t}\sin(z)dz+A \\
g(x-2t) &= -\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{x-2t}\sin(z)dz+B \\
\end{align}

As $0 = f(x+2t)+g(x-2t)$, then $A+B=0$ gives us the following solution

\begin{align}
u(x,t) &=\frac{1}{4}\int_{x-2t}^{x+2t}\sin(z)dz \\
&=\frac{\cos(x-2t)-\cos(x+2t)}{4} \\
&=\sin(x)\frac{\sin(2t)}{2}
\end{align}

I would like to know if my solution is correct and if there is another, faster way to solve this equation.

Comment: The only "faster" way would have been separation of variables

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? I first tried the separation variable but I couldn't get the solution.

Comment: Why didn't separation of variables work for you? Do you mind posting your work up to the point you got stuck?

Comment: To verify your solution, check it satisfies the PDE (it does) and the boundary conditions (it does). So it's a correct solution.

Comment: Just so you know, the symbol $\Bbb R^+$ is a lot lot more common than $\Bbb R_+$ especially at more advanced levels